# CRM 2013 reorder entities in sitemap ribbon

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

How do you reorder the entities in the ribbon? I see a lot of stuff on how to organize the ribbon inside an entity but not one level above that.

Comment: show screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to import this almost lost tool in order to do it. Why did they not just include this functionality OTB.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/develop1/archive/2013/08/06/dude-where-39-s-my-site-map-editor